# Decomposition of matrix in terms of projectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-decomposition

I wanted to understand the following decomposition of a operator relative $A$ to the direct sum $H \oplus H^{\perp}$ that I have seen in literature (in connection with Stinespring theorem) where $P$ is a projector:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
PA|_{H} & P^{\perp}A|_{H}\\
PA|_{H^{\perp}} & P^{\perp}A|_{H^{\perp}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am familiar with the decomposition:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
PAP & P^{\perp}AP\\
PAP^{\perp} & P^{\perp}AP^{\perp}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

for which the calculation is clear.

I wanted to start to understand this using a matrix like

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or a right shift operator.

But that means constructing the restriction $A|_{H}$, how would I go about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a relatively nice exploratory example, I would recommend considering 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}, \quad H = \{(t,t,t): t \in \Bbb C\}
$$
You could consider the restriction of $A$ to $H$ or to its orthogonal complement